# Where can I safely download older TYPO3 releases?

Tags: typo3

Back then, I was able to download older subversions of TYPO3 CMS on SourceForge which saved me a lot of time and anger.

Now I am facing a problem and I think it is a bug in the current used version. I would like to test it with an other instance, but as it seems it is not being stored anywhere. I will use an vulnerable version for now, but that is not what I actually want.

Maybe I've overseen a link or something. Do you know where I could find a list of all downloadable TYPO3 Versions? I know I can google it, but I don't want to use 3rd party sources ether...

I'd say that TYPO3 on SourceForge should still be updated...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All versions can be downloaded from get.typo3.org directly. Example for a very old 4.5:

```
wget --content-disposition https://get.typo3.org/4.5.38
```

Comment: Perfect! It is actually made even easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use https://get.typo3.org/ for this. Simply append the version number to the URL to download the desired version, e.g. https://get.typo3.org/8.7.15 to download version 8.7.15 of TYPO3 (8.7.16 is the latest ATM.)

If you use Composer you can enforce a downgrade with something like this:

```
composer require typo3/cms 8.7.15
```

Or:

```
composer require typo3/cms-core:8.7.15 typo3/cms-backend:8.7.15 ...
```

Notice that this replaces the version constraint in your Composer manifest with a fixed version which should be changed back as soon as possible.